# Programmatically defining a class: type vs types.new_class

Tags: python

Aside from `types.new_class`'s capability to define the keyword arguments when creating a class. Are there any major differences between the two approaches?

```
import types

First = type('First',(object,),{'asd':99})
k = First()

Second = types.new_class('Second',(object,),{},lambda x:x)
x = Second()
```

Answer (score 15):

#### Are there any major differences between the two approaches?

**Yes**. The answer involves a concept called "[metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/7246614)".

> [Metaclasses] are deeper magic than 99% of users should
> ever worry about.  If you wonder whether you need them, you don't (the
> people who actually need them know with certainty that they need them, and
> don't need an explanation about why). *⸺ Tim Peters, author of Zen of Python ([source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/o61KSF77IWs/s09TqSEvTQgJ))*

**If you think you're in that 99%, then read no further, feel free to just use [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=type%20built#type). It's just as good as [`types.new_class`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.new_class) except for in the rare situation that you're using metaclasses.**

If you want to know more about metaclasses, I suggest you **take a look at some of the high quality answers posted to "[What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/7246614)".** (I recommend [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/7246614).)

Once you understand what a metaclass is, the answer is fairly self-evident. Since `type` is a specific metaclass, it will only work if you want to create classes that use it as their metaclass.

However, if you want to use a non-default metaclass

```py
class MySimpleMeta(type):
    pass
```

and a static class won't do

```py
class MyStaticClass(object, metaclass=MySimpleMeta):
    pass
```

then you can use `types.new_class`

```py
import types

MyStaticClass = types.new_class("MyStaticClass", (object,), {"metaclass": MySimpleMeta}, lambda ns: ns)
# this is equivalent to the above class.
```

(As a brief aside, the reason that it requires a callable (e.g. `lambda ns: ns`) instead of a dictionary is [because metaclasses are allowed to care about the order in which the attributes are defined.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/#id11) )

Comment: Just to add to this, you can already create a new class dynamically using a statically known metaclass (as you pointed out), e.g. `MyStaticClass = MySimpleMeta("MyStaticClass", (), {})`. The advantage of `new_class` is it allows the metaclass itself to be determined dynamically.

Comment: In the light of the comment from @Ben above, this answer becomes pointless. It's that comment which correctly answers the question (that `new_class` allows dynamic determination of metaclass).

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is late, and hence you've already likely answered this yourself.

Firstly, it seems that you misunderstand the `kwds` argument of `types.new_class`; it is the class keyword arguments, e.g

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs, **config):
        print(config)
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **config):
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class SomeCls(metaclass=MyMeta, debug=True):
    pass

>> {'debug': True}
```

is analogous to (without the print)

```
SomeCls = types.new_class("SomeCls", (), {'debug':True})
```

These meta-arguments are useful when configuring meta-classes.

I am not really sure as to why `new_class` was designed to accept a callable vs a dict directly, but I suspect it was to avoid implicit shared state between "new" classes that did not inherit from one another.